# Artifact on UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

I've created a `UITableView` and am using a custom `UITableViewCell` for the first row of this table. The only issue is there is some sort of artifact in the top left hand corner. Clicking in the area where this box is causes it to temporarily disappear and then reappear again. The  box is always there. The `UITableViewCell` consists of the following:

- `UITextView` (Description)
- `UIImageView` (Image on far right)
- `UILabel` (Character count)

I've tried removing all of these subviews and the box still appears.

[image: Tableview artifact]
[image: Artifact with blended layers turned on]

Comment: Yea, this is common. It's a problem with using custom cells with UITableViewStyleGrouped. I've had to essentially implement my own version of grouped style before. =/

Comment: Are you adding the subviews to `contentView`?

Comment: Yes I am. What should I be adding it to?

Answer (score 1):

If the box still appears even if you remove all the subviews of your custom cell, then it must be coming from another cell which has a frame outside its bounds. For example, a header view. One way to test this is to make sure you enable subview clipping for all your views.

Comment: The other cells are all the standard UITableViewCell's with style UITableViewCellStyleDefault. There is no header or footer view. I've set these cells to cliptobounds and it still happens.